# FastAPI - AsyncPG - sqlAlchemy - cannot use Connection.transaction() in a manually started transaction

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, asyncpg

I'm using this boilerplate https://github.com/grillazz/fastapi-sqlalchemy-asyncpg

to make use of SQLAlchemy/AsyncPG in FastAPI. Everything is working fine for a few hours before after a few incoming requests I get the following message on each following incoming request:

```
(sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.InterfaceError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError'>: cannot use Connection.transaction() in a manually started transaction
```

Do you know what could be the cause for this ? I do not use transactions.

Cheers,
Henry

Answer (score 0):

it would hard to figure out the cause without look at the code. But one thing to know is that regardless of you explicitly starting a transaction or not, `asyncpg` would issue a transaction begin whenever you're putting/modifying data.

You can turn on the `echo` feature when creating your sqlalchemy engine to see all the issued sql queries, i assume you would be able to see when your statements are issuing the trasnaction(`begin`) statement to the database.

Just by reading at the error message, it seems like there's an error between two transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issues before(with FastAPI), and the root cause was that some database connections didn't close successfully. After extensive experimentation, I discovered that if a coroutine within `asyncio.gather` raised an exception, it could potentially lead to issues with closing the database connections used in other coroutines. Therefore, my advice is to avoid using async sessions within any `asyncio.gather` to prevent such problems.